# How to get .whl files to open with a custom batch script?

Tags: python, batch-file, pip

(Windows 10 64 bit, Python 3.6.1)

I want to create a batch script and set all .whl files to open with it. I want the Batch script file to use run a command that causes pip to install the .whl file. 
Below is an example of the command I want it to run:

```
pip install the_whl_file_you_just_clicked_on
```

My only problem with this is getting the .whl file's path to be automatically passed to the script as an arugument. I would be very grateful if someone could help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you [associate the `.whl` extension with your script](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/change-file-associations-windows) as you appear to be going to do, the file you open will be passed to the script as the first (and sole) argument by default:

```
pip install "%1"
```